# Grunt serve command throws error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

When execute `grunt serve` after generating yeoman project using `yo angular` command, I get following error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'grunt-legacy-util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/angular/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:26:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

How can I resolve above errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you correctly install the node module `grunt-legacy-util` in your repo using `npm install` if it's already in the dependencies of your `package.json` ?

Otherwise run the command :

```
npm install --save grunt-legacy-util
```

Answer (score 1):

delete the node_modules directory and run npm install command again. It should work.